# XSL - HTML table footer displaying dynamically in position ( changing as per the number of rows in a table )

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XSL sheet embedded with HTML tags, from which I generate a PDF using Java. I'm able to generate the PDF using this XSL stylesheet.
In my XSL i have a model like :

```
Page 1:

Header 
 Table
    row 1
    row 2
    row 3
    row 4
    row 5
Footer

Page 2:

Header 
 Table
    row 6
    row 7
    row 8
    row 9
    row 10
Footer

Page 3:

Header 
 Table
    row 11
    row 12
    row 13
Footer
```

I should have show table rows 5 per page with Header and Footer. The problem is, I have to show the footer as a static content irrespective of the number of rows in the table.

for example: if the table contains 5 rows or 4 or 3 or 2 or 1, the footer should be at the bottom of the page. Instead, it is displaying dynamically under the table, as the table size changes.

Please find my XSL Stylesheet code below :

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$Header"/>

<xsl:copy-of select="$OrderRowsHeader"/>

<xsl:for-each select="orders">
    <table style=" width: 100%; height: 13mm;">

        <tr style="font-size: 10px; border: 0">
                        <td width="14mm" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"><xsl:value-of select="number" /></td>
                        <td width="36mm" style=" text-align: left; vertical-align: top;"><xsl:value-of select="code" /></td>
                        <td width="47mm" style=" text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" ><xsl:value-of select="description" /></td>
                        <td width="12mm" style=" text-align: left; vertical-align: top;"><xsl:value-of select="units" /></td>
                        <td width="16mm" style=" text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"><xsl:value-of select="quantity" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <xsl:if test="(position() mod 5) = 0 and ( position() !=  last() )">

            <xsl:copy-of select="$ReportFooter" />
            <div style="page-break-before: always" />

            <xsl:copy-of select="$Header"/>

            <xsl:copy-of select="$OrderRowsHeader"/>

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:copy-of select="$ReportFooter" />



<xsl:variable name="ReportFooter">
    <table style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; ">
        <tr style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <td width="150mm" style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8px;">
            </td> 
                Some Text here......
            </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="OrderRowsHeader">
    <table style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">

                    <tr style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; font-size: 9px; border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <th width="18mm" style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse;">Line</th>
                        <th width="45mm" style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse;">Product code</th>
                        <th width="63mm" style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse;">Description</th>
                        <th width="18mm" style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse;">Units</th>
                        <th width="16mm" style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse;">Qty</th>
                    </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running into a styling issue. Your solution is found in CSS. I won't address any of your code besides what is relevant to the footer.

```
<xsl:variable name="ReportFooter">
    <table style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; ">
        <tr style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <td width="150mm" style="border: solid thin #c0c0c0; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8px;">
        </td> 
            Some Text here......
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:variable>
```

The properties I've added to add to the table are: `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`

`position: absolute` will have the table ignore the flow of the page (meaning it does not flow relative to other elements), and `bottom` is a measurement of how far it is from the bottom of the page, so `bottom: 0` will put it at the bottom of the parent container.